# "Using walk mode through keyboard in X3DOM"

Tags: javascript, x3d, x3dom

I want to use walk mode from my keyboard arrow keys using `X3DOM`. I searched a lot on this,  I have not got any customized keywords that can be used in `X3DOM`, all are under predefined keywords. I want to use user defined keywords for `x3dom application`. Is it possible? If so, can someone help?

Comment: you can use UserInteractivitySensorNodes (eg. KeySensor) to receive user input from the keyboard